# connecting rate button before app is submited

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've searched forums for this topic. The answer I got is to use

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID
```

an a following way:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID")!)
```

Where I get APP_ID from itunes connect.

The frustrating thing is that **app id** is defined in Member Center and it looks like myappname(com.mycompany.myappname). The only thing that I see in iTunes Connects is Apple ID. So which one should I use? Also, when submitting the app, I got a mail in return that stated that the app id is in the form `1033017031` and not `myappname`

Comment: Use app id in itunesconnect.

Comment: You mean apple ID. there is no app id in itunesconnect

Comment: Yes, in "General Information", use "Apple ID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the link you are looking for. It will be available when you will register application in https://itunesconnect.apple.com and will not be changed after application distribution

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I got the link by hovering over. When clicked, it said that I cannot access to that item in the app store. I guess that is normal until the app gets reviewed.

Comment: yes application will be available after successful publishing